# How do I get a total of written data by process and by file on a linux system?

Tags: linux, monitoring, resource-usage

I need to collect some data on how much each process on my system writes to a certain disk. I'm only interested in a grand total after say a week. I also need something similar for files. I.e. I'd like to know the top 10 of files that have the most data written to them in a week and exactly how much was written to each.

To illustrate, the end-result should be two tables/textfiles/whatever manageable file format that have data like this:

By process:

```
Process          Total amount of data written to /dev/sda by that process in a week
--------         ----------
logdaemon        101 GB
gvfsd-sftp --spawner :1.19 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/2 [pool]   30 GB
openoffice       50 GB
[jbd2/dm-0-2]     2 GB
...
```

By file:

```
File                                             Total amount written to that file last week
--------                                         --------
/var/log/some_giant_logfile.log                  100 GB
/home/confus/Videos/great_big_video.mpg           16 GB
...
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a bash script to do this... and set it up in crontab to run weekly and write its output to a file

*identify how much a specific process has written to a file like so:

```
#get its pid
PID=`ps -ef | awk '/<process_name>/ {print $2}'`
#print out size and filename
lsof -p ${PID} | awk '/<file_you_want>/ {print $7"\t"$NF}' | sort -u
#find out device on which above file is located
df /path/to/file_you_want | awk '/\/dev/ {print $0}'
```

*calculate how much has been written in one week to a file as so:

```
#issue the below command and save the output to a file
NEW=`du /path/to/file_you_want | tee -a  /path/to/store_value.txt`
#read the output one week later
OLD_VAL=`grep '/path/to/file_you_want' /path/to/store_value.txt | awk '{print $1}'`
#overwrite new value and store it in memory
NEW=`du /path/to/file_you_wan | tee -a  /path/to/store_value.txt`
NEW_VAL=`echo $NEW | awk '{print $1}'`
#calculate delta
DELTA=`echo "${NEW_VAL}-${OLD_VAL}" | bc
# print the amount of bytes that have been written in 1 week
echo $DELTA
```

Comment: what does `du` have to do with bytes written to a file? it only works for bytes `appended` to the file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm only partially answering your very first sentence here, amount of data written by process, linking those IO to which disk will need more work to correlate process IO and disk IO informations (and is likely to break on high IO loads).

One option for this information is using [netdata](https://github.com/firehol/netdata/wiki) which record disk read and writes by application.

You may store this into a timeseries DB like infuxDB (netdata can do this natively) and then get the values per app aggregated with grafana or any other qury tool, or take inspiration from the app plugin [source code](https://github.com/firehol/netdata/blob/master/src/apps_plugin.c) to get the values by process parsing the /proc filesystem for necessary informations.
An exemple on how to get information (swap) for all processes is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32327705/3627607) (I link to my own answer as it doesn't loop over `find` result and it is a real improvement in speed)

Another option *may be* to dig into the [audit daemon](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-auditd/) on linux to see if aureport can give you the informations you're after. I never configured auditd for this purpose, there's a bunch of tutorial about it on google covering various aspects but this particular one sounds like you'll need to dig into the man pages and test a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To get a live view for "by process" I would recommend:

```
sudo iotop -a -o -P
```

'-a' accumulates the data read/written
'-o' shows only the processes with I/O
'-P' shows processes onyl instead of all running threads

Downside: If a process finishes after each run, it is not seen by iotop.

To find frequently changing files I use this command:

```
sudo inotifywait -e modify -e attrib -e move -e create -e delete -m -r  /var /home
```

You maybe need to increase the number of watches:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 180000 > /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches"
```

This will not show you the amount of data written, but it will help track down qhat files are being changed and how often.

Comment: I came across this tool because a was searching what program kills my SSD's lifetime.